# How do I get the timezone from a string containing a datetime value in PHP?

Tags: datetime, php

Given the following string: `2011/09/18 11:59PM EDT, 2011-09-18T23:59:59+00:00`

How do I extract the timezone part from this string using PHP?

Comment: Do you mean "how do I parse out the EDT?"  Or do you mean something else?  Please provide some more details.

Comment: Got the solutn below answer is what i need.thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a new [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object from the string, and use [`getTimezone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimezone.php) on it to get the timezone:

```
$time = '2011/09/18 11:59PM EDT';
$dt = new DateTime($time);
print_r($dt->getTimezone()->getName());
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/ZNFop)**.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that when timezone is not specified in the time string it'll return default timezone instead of null.